# need to have sql query that returns all data except the one with only zeros

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the two following tables :

[image: data table]

[image: hosts table]

i need to get all rows from data table with the following conditions :
- i don't want rows where for one id all values are 0
- i want to have instead of ip address the corresponding hostname retrieved from hosts table

I have tried the following query:

```
select time, hostname , id , value from data , hosts where hosts.ip_address = data.host group by time,id having avg(value) <> 0;
```

but it is not what i want. 
The expected result is :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QkWxJ.png)

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. Can you add a mock up table showing what result you want?

Answer (score 2):

Did you try this ?

```
select d.time, h.hostname , d.id , d.value from data d join hosts h where
h.ip_address = d.host group by d.time,d.id having avg(value) <> 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

i hope this help you, i test this with your raw data

```
select [time] 
   ,hostname
   ,id
   ,value
  from @data as d
 left join @host h on d.host=h.ip_address
 where id not in (select id from @data where value=0  group by id having 
 count(value)>1)
```